# Can I safely cast C# Math.Round() to an integer?

Tags: c#, floating-point

Given a double value x, I would like to cast with

```
int y = (int)Math.Round(x);
```

Is this code safe?  Do there exist non-integer C# representations of doubles that could inadvertantly truncate?

Comment: Yes it is safe, but see the duplicate for an alternate method

Comment: What about NaN, infinity, and -infinity?